# How to create and destroy a channel in Agora?

Tags: agora.io

I'm making a mobile app for an audio chat like the clubhouse. Does anyone knows how to get existing rooms? In other words, how could you tell when a room is created and destroyed? I wonder if a channel is something like a river that constantly flows even without people in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's an interesting question. Creating and destroying can be done in multiple ways which mainly depends upon your use case:

- Pre-defined channels: If you want your users to join some existing channel itself then just pass the name of the channel to the `joinChannel()` method.
- User can create their own channel: Process is still the same, in this case you just have to pass the channel name that the user gives as an input.

Further the process is simple the user calls the `leaveChannel()` method to drop off a particular call. And then the `destroy()` method releases all the Agora RtcEngine resources.